# Dynamically add a Dojo-enabled Element in Zend

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

I'm writing a form using `Zend_Dojo_Form`.

Everything goes fine, unless I dynamically insert elements into the form (using ajax, the user can add more elements by clicking a [+] button).

I managed to insert my new `Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect` into the page, but the element isn't dojo-enabled (no auto-completion, or tundra styling).

I'm guessing dojo transforms existing form elements once the page is loaded the first time, and doesn't parse them again when a new node is added... But I can't find how to tell dojo there's new elements in town.

What I've tried:

- Executing `dojo.parser.parse();` or `dojo.parser.parse('id_of_new_element');` after the insertion of a new element
- Adding `Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_Dojo::setUseDeclarative();` in my Dojo_Form's init() method (as seen on [nabble's forums](http://old.nabble.com/Dijit-elements-and-xhrPost-td20276334.html))

My method for adding new elements is the one described by [Jeremy Kendall](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/).

I don't know if my problem comes from an incompatibility with Zend, Dojo, or if I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling I finally managed to get it running.

In [Jeremy Kendall's javascript code](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/) you have to insert the following script in the **function ajaxAddField()**

```
// Insert new element before the Add button
$("#addElement-label").before(newElement);

// Parse the element to receive Dojo style
var n = dojo.byId("newName" + id);
n.outerHTML = newElement;
dojo.parser.parse(n);
```

and replace

```
searchString = '*[id^=newName' + lastId + '-]';
$(searchString).remove()
```

in the **function removeField()** by

```
// Destroy dijits before destroying the node
var n = dojo.byId("newName" + lastId);
var dijits = dijit.findWidgets(n);
if (dijits) {
    for (var i = 0, n = dijits.length; i < n; i++) {
        dijits[i].destroyRecursive();
    }
}
dijits = dojo.parser.parse("newName" + lastId);

// Destroy the node
dojo.destroy("newName" + lastId);
```

Maybe there is still a better way to do it, but it worked for me. When removing the node, the [dijits have to be destroyed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212823/dojo-parser-parse-doesnt-always-return) since otherwise the HTML fragment will not get parsed again.